# How to set vaue of attribute samesite on the cookie __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__

Tags: html, token, antiforgerytoken, samesite

I have an antirforgery token(@Html.AntiForgeryToken()) on a cshtml page, which generates a cookie
**RequestVerificationToken_Lw**. The attribute values on this cookie are HTTP and Secure. But I need the SameSite also to be set. How do I achieve this?

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

__RequestVerificationToken_Lw__
```

Comment: wild guess.. set it up in your startup class ?
_services.AddAntiforgery(options =>  { options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict ; });_

Answer (score 4):

Can this help?

in Global.asax.cs

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {

        protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender,EventArgs e) {
            // This code will mark the __RequestVerificationToken cookie SameSite=Strict 
            if (Request.Cookies.Count>0) {
                foreach (string s in Request.Cookies.AllKeys) {
                    if (s.ToLower() == "__requestverificationtoken") {
                        HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies[s];
                        c.SameSite = System.Web.SameSiteMode.Strict;
                        Response.Cookies.Set(c);
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
 }
```

Comment: `SameSite` not available before .NET Framework 4.7.2 :-(

Comment: @PaulB., in earlier .Net you can use `c.Path += "; SameSite=Strict";`.  (NB: you may want to check for an existing `SameSite`-part first.)

Comment: This LOOKS LIKE it actually adds the cookie a second time, not overwrites the cookie

Comment: I would advise against this. The code as written loops through the cookies being sent by the client (Request.Cookies) and adds them to the Response. You can confirm with curl by trying `curl -I https://<websiteurl>/ -H "Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=BadCookie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly"`. The server will return `set-cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=BadCookie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax` 

You will also see two Set-Cookie headers returned because the server is not being sent the VerificationToken that it expects.